# Representing 4×4 Matrix A with Minimal Constants for Linear Transformation Image Spanned by $\{u, v, w\}$ and Kernel Spanned by $\{s\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

### Question

Let $\{u, v, w, s ∈ ℝ^4\}$ be a non-orthogonal basis set in $ℝ^4$. Consider a linear transformation $f_A$ with a 4×4 square matrix $A$. Given that the image of $f_A$ is spanned by $\langle u, v, w \rangle$ and the kernel is spanned by $\langle s \rangle$, how can matrix $A$ be represented using the minimal necessary constants?

### My answer

$$
\begin{align}
Au &= au + bv + cw \\
Av &= du + ev + fw \\
Aw &= gu + hv + iw \\
As &= 0
\end{align}
$$

Thus

$$
A = (au + bv + cw, du + ev + fw, gu + hv + iw, 0)(u, v, w)^T
$$

Answer (score 0):

The columns of $A$ are linear combinations of only $u, v, w$, therefore,

$A = [u, v, w] B $

where $B$ is $ 3 \times 4 $.

We also require that $B s = 0 $, so that $A s = 0 $.

Therefore, the $3$ rows of $B$ are any three vectors from the orthogonal complement of $s$.  The orthogonal complement of $s$ is set of all $x$ such that

$ x^T s = 0 $

This is a $3$-dimensional vector space.

To be more explicit, if $C$ is any basis of the orthogonal complement, then we can write

$ B^T = C M $

where $M$ is an arbitrary $3 \times 3$ matrix.  Hence

$A=[u,v,w] M^T C^T $